# compare text files, display items that match - Python

Tags: python

I have 4 text files in the following formats. I'm trying to compare the text files 'keycountry.txt' with 'country.txt' and 'keylink.txt' with 'link.txt'. I want to display the 'country' and the 'link' that matches/common to 'keycountry' and 'keylink' files respectively.

I had written a code that prints only 'country' and 'links' that match but wasn't able to print when it doesn't match. Below I have shown how the output should look like.

The code that I implemented can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776219/python-comparing-text-file-if-else-printing). I was having an issue with if-else printing.

Is there a simple and efficient way to do this?

keycountry.txt

```
UK USA Germany
```

country.txt

```
Brexit - UK
USA UK Relations
France win world cup
```

keylink.txt

```
www.abc.com
www.ddd.com
www.eee.com
```

link.txt

```
www.abc.com
www.eee.com
```

The output, if it matches, should be like:

```
LINKS
www.abc.com
www.eee.com
matching

COUNTRY
Brexit-UK
USA UK Relations
matching
```

The output, if it doesn't match, should be like:

```
LINKS
No matches found
COUNTRY
No matches found
```